# Printing All Values via File Writer

Tags: java

I want to print all the letter that the user will input but the thing is, my program only prints the last value that the user will input, and only the last value is recorded in `Ascii.txt`. It should look like this

for example : the user input A,B,c,C

I want also to delete the comma but I can't :(

output in "Ascii.txt" should be:

```
A = 65
B = 66
c = 99
C = 67
```

please dont laugh at me because im still a student and new to programming, thank you very much

```
import java.io.*;

public class NewClass2{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{



  BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.println("Please Enter  letters separated by comma: ");

  String str = buff.readLine();
  for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i )
  {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    int j = (int) c;
    System.out.println(c +" = " + j);
    {
      try
      {
         FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Ascii.txt");
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

         out.write(c+"  =  "+j);
         out.close();

       }catch (Exception e){
       }
     }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can use `String.split(",")` to get a `String[]` of the numbers between the commas.

Comment: You are opening/closing the filestream on each loop. Hence only the last line is present in the output once the program is done.  Move the open/close code outside the loop.

Comment: oh thank you sir, but how do you remove the comma in the "Ascii.txt" ?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that you close and re-open the `FileStream` for each character you want to dump to your ASCII-File. Thus, your file will be emptied before writing a character. Just move the creation and closing of the stream outside the loop.

```
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please Enter  letters separated by comma: ");

    String str = buff.readLine();
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try
    {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Ascii.txt");
        out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i )
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            int j = c;
            System.out.println(c + " = " + j);

            out.write(c + "  =  " + j);

        }
    }

    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        ;
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( out != null )
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

In order to remove the commas from the output I would suggest to use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    //...          
    String[] splittedStr = str.split(",");
    for ( int i = 0; i < splittedStr.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( splittedStr[i].length() > 0 )
        {
            char c = splittedStr[i].charAt(0);
            int j = c;

            out.write(c + "  =  " + j);
        }
    }
    //...
```

Comment: oh thank you sir, but how do you remove the comma in the "Ascii.txt" ?

Answer (score 0):

You only write in your file AFTER your loop on str.

```
BufferedWriter out;
try{
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Ascii.txt");
out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ){
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  int j = (int) c;
  System.out.println(c +" = " + j);
  out.write(c+"  =  "+j);
} catch ...{
...
} finally {
   if (out!=null) 
     out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you're closing the stream every time you writes to the file. Maybe you were looking for the `flush()` method.

Just to complement, if you're using Java 7, you can use the try with resources (so you don't have to bother with closing it):

```
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Please Enter  letters separated by comma: ");

String str = buff.readLine();

try( BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Ascii.txt"))){
   //Using split
   String[] splitted = str.split(",");
   for(String s : splitted){
      char c = s.charAt(0);
      int j = c;
      out.write(c + "  =  " + j);
   }
}catch(Exception E){
   //You really should catch specific exceptions here.
}
```